# Iterating over array not working for data though nested fetch using react

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

I am obtaining data after making multiple fetch requests through chaining. I want to display the data on the page in the form of a table. But when I try to map over the object, iteration doesn't work.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getResources = async() => {
            await getUserResourceId()
                .then((data) => {
                    const resourceId = data.resourceId;
                    getPersonalGroup(resourceId)
                        .then((responseData) => {
                            personalGroup = responseData.result;
                       
                 getPersonalGroupResourceId(personalGroup, 24)
                .then((resourceData) => {
                    resourceData.forEach((resourceId) => {
                        getIndividualResourceId(resourceId)
                            .then((resources) => {
                                testData.push(resources);
                                console.log('resourceData', resources);
                            });
                    });
                });
              });
          });             


 }
    getResources();
}, []);
```

When I display testData, the result is :
[image]

Because testData has no value initially, the mapping is not working as well. So iterating over the data and displaying part is not working.
How do I store the data, once all the pending resources are fetched ? Adding await is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `async/await` syntax all the way through (no chaining with `.then`).
2. When looping over `resourceData` push each unresolved promise into an array.
3. Resolve them all with `const newTestData = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
4. Update your `testData` stored in the component state with `newTestData`: `setTestData(newTestData);`.
5. When using your `testData` in the template, coditionally render the component that uses it `{testData.length && <SomeComponent data={testData} />}`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the 2nd point -- pushing unresolved promise into an array. How to put a check if its yet unresolved ?

Comment: You don't need to "check" for it, you know that a Promise is unresolved if you haven't done anything to resolve it. There are 2 ways of doing it: `await` and `.then`. Don't do either of those inside your forEach loop and just push each `getIndividualResourceId(resourceId)` into an array and then resolve them all at once.

Understanding of how to work with Promises seems to be the crucial piece of information missing here. I'd recommend reading a few "understanding js promises" articles of which there are many.